# How to fix expandable tree in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement an expandable and collapsible tree using d3.js.
But it seems like not working.

Can someone suggest how to fix this?

I mean I'm not being able to expand and toggle it like the following demo:

https://observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/horizontal-collapsible-d3-flextree

Following is my implementation in vue.js:

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      mounted() {
        var width = 960,
          height = 500;

        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        const svg = d3.select(createSvg `<svg width=500 height=500></svg>`);
        const g = svg
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
          .attr('transform', `translate(100,${height/2})`)


        const duration = 750;
        let i = 0,
          root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
            return d.children;
          });

        // Collapse after second level
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        root.x0 = 0;
        root.y0 = 0;

        // Reverse size parameters, in order to maintain order in horizontal layout 
        loopOverHierarchy(treeData, d => {
          if (Array.isArray(d.size)) {
            if (!d._size) d._size = d.size.slice();
            d.size = d._size.slice().reverse();
          }
        })


        const flexLayout = flextree.flextree();

        update(root);

        // Collapse the node and all it's children
        function collapse(d) {
          if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children
            d._children.forEach(collapse)
            d.children = null
          }
        }

        function loopOverHierarchy(d, callback) {
          callback(d);
          if (d.children) d.children.forEach(c => loopOverHierarchy(c, callback))
          if (d._children) d._children.forEach(c => loopOverHierarchy(c, callback))
        }

        function update(source) {

          // Assigns the x and y position to the nodes
          var treeData = flexLayout(root);

          // Switch x and y coordinates for horizontal layout
          treeData.each(d => {
            const x = d.x;
            d.x = d.y;
            d.y = x;
          })

          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
            links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

          // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

          // Update the nodes...
          var node = g.selectAll('g.node')
            .data(nodes, d => d.id || (d.id = ++i));

          // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
            })
            .on('click', click);

          // Add Circle for the nodes
          nodeEnter.append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('r', 1e-6)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
            });

          // Add labels for the nodes
          nodeEnter.append('text')
            .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
            .attr('dy', '0.35em')
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.data.name;
            })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

          // UPDATE
          var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node)
            .attr("fill", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-width", "3px;")
            .style('font', '12px sans-serif')

          // Transition to the proper position for the node
          nodeUpdate.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(event, i, arr) {
              const d = d3.select(this).datum();
              return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

          // Update the node attributes and style
          nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
            .attr('r', 20)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
            })
            .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


          // Remove any exiting nodes
          var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(event, i, arr) {
              const d = d3.select(this).datum();
              return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
            })
            .remove();

          // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
          nodeExit.select('circle')
            .attr('r', 1e-6);

          // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
          nodeExit.select('text')
            .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)



          // ****************** links section ***************************

          // Update the links...
          var link = g.selectAll('path.link')
            .data(links, function(d) {
              return d.id;
            });

          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr('d', function(d) {
              var o = {
                x: source.x0,
                y: source.y0
              }
              return diagonal(o, o)
            });

          // UPDATE
          var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2px")

          // Transition back to the parent element position
          linkUpdate.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(d) {
              return diagonal(d, d.parent)
            });

          // Remove any exiting links
          var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(event, i, arr) {
              const d = d3.select(this).datum();
              var o = {
                x: source.x,
                y: source.y
              }
              return diagonal(o, o)
            })
            .remove();

          // Store the old positions for transition.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
          });

          // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
          function diagonal(s, d) {
            const path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
        C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
          ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
          ${d.x} ${d.y}`

            return path
          }

          // Toggle children on click.
          function click(event, d) {
            if (d.children) {
              d._children = d.children;
              d.children = null;
            } else {
              d.children = d._children;
              d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
          }
        }

      })
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="tree-graph"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[The biggest change between v5 and v6](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0) is that `d3.event` no longer exists and the first argument to any `.on()` function is now the event, not the datum. That has become the second argument. This also has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/5015356) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63998592/5015356).

Simply changing `click(d)` to `click(e, d)` fixed the issue.
Label positions are not updated, but that is because you never implemented that. This fixes the collapsing nodes at least.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var treeData = {
      name: "Top Level",
      children: [{
          name: "Level 2: A",
          children: [{
            name: "Son of A"
          }, {
            name: "Daughter of A"
          }],
        },
        {
          name: "Level 2: B"
        },
      ],
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("#tree-graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    //root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }
    }

    function update(source) {
      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(e, d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate
        .select("circle.node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr("cursor", "pointer");

      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link
        .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        });

      link
        .enter()
        .insert("text", "g")
        .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .attr("fill", "Orange")
        .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return (
            "translate(" +
            (d.parent.y + d.y) / 2 +
            "," +
            (d.parent.x + d.x) / 2 +
            ")"
          );
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent);
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          };
          return diagonal(o, o);
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {
        let path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
          ${d.y} ${d.x}`;

        return path;
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(e, d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="tree-graph"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
```